# EAGLE PCB, how to specify an out-of-board component?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

This might be a very basic question. I have a schematic where some of the components are outside of the board.

For example, for a power supply, I have a switch and a transformer that are on the schematic, but I want them to be placed outside of the PCB, for this I want to place the appropriate pads to allow some wires to be soldered. What's the right way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create a new device whose footprint (package) matches the pads you want to solder to on the PCB.

Your off-board transformer can be represented as a transformer-looking symbol on your schematic with pins connecting to components elsewhere on the schematic. But you can make its package drawing as just the necessary number of pads in a row. When you place the device in your schematic, it will manifest as just solder pads on the PCB layout.